# python3 bytes construct adding spurrious bytes

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python 3. I am sending bytes across the wire. 
When I send `s.send(b'\x8f\x35\x4a\x5f")`, and I look at the stack trace, I only see `5f4a358f`.

However, if I create a variable:

```
test=(['\x8f\x35\x4a\x5f'])
print(str(''.join(test).encode()))
```

I receive `b'\xc2\x8f5J_'`
As you can see, there is an extra byte `/xc2`.

My question is two-fold:
1) Why when using str.encode() which encodes a string to bytes which are already "encoded" an extra byte /xc2 is added whereas a literal byte string b'\x8f\x35\x4a\x5f' has no extra encoding is added?
2) If I am passing in bytes into a variable which is used as a buffer to send data across a socket, how does one create and send a set of literal bytes (e.g. b') programmatically  such that there is no added /xc2 byte when sent across the wire?

Thank you all for your time! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's *not* encoded; it's text consisting of U+008F U+0035 U+004A U+005F. And then when *you* encode it (as UTF-8, per default) the extra byte is added. Either use `bytes` in the first place, or encode as Latin-1. But use `bytes`.